# How to Replace Error Values into 0? R Language

Tags: r

I am trying to replace error values (444.0) with 0. I could find replace NaN with 0, but not error values. Is it possible to replace 444.0 by the same way NaN?

My data looks like this:

```
>ErinJan[,3,1] # January 2013 data for Erin
                   .
                   .
                   .
                 [,1]
         [2880,] 444.0
         [2881,] 444.0
         [2882,] 444.0
         [2883,] 444.0
         [2884,] 444.0
         [2885,]   0.0
         [2886,]   0.0
         [2887,]   0.0
         [2888,]   0.0
        [2889,]   0.0
        [2890,]   0.0
        [2891,]   0.0
        [2892,] -16.3
        [2893,] -16.4
        [2894,] -16.5
        [2895,] -16.5
        [2896,] -16.5
        [2897,] -16.3
        [2898,] -16.2
        [2899,] -16.1
        [2900,] -16.3
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

I tried this:

```
ErinJan2013 <- replace(ErinJan[,3,1],444.0,0)
```

This did not help. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you,
YH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ErinJan2013[ErinJan2013 == 444.0] = 0
```

Comment: That is super easy solution. Thank you!